# Excluding snake's coordinates from those of random foods in Snake Game

Tags: python, random, pygame

I'm working on a Snake Game project. When you start the game, a food pops up in a random place on the screen; however, there's also a chance that the food can pop up on the snake. How can I fix this issue?
Here is my code:

**snake_game.py**

```
import pygame
import sys

from random import randint

from settings import Settings 
from snake import Snake
from food import Food 

class SnakeGame:
    '''The main class of the game.'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialize the game assets, screen, etc.'''
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,
                            self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")

        self.snake_parts = pygame.sprite.Group() #Will do some refactoring here.
        self.snake_part = Snake(self)  # Will move this part elsewhere.
        self.snake_parts.add(self.snake_part)
        self.food = Food(self)
       
    def run_game(self):
        '''The main loop of the game.'''
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_snake_parts()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        '''Check all the events.'''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        '''Check keydown events.'''
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
            self.snake_part.m_up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            self.snake_part.m_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            self.snake_part.m_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
            self.snake_part.m_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        '''Check keyup events.'''
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
            self.snake_part.m_up = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            self.snake_part.m_down = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            self.snake_part.m_left = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
            self.snake_part.m_right = False

    def _check_snake_food_collisions(self):
        '''Check the collisions between the snake and foods.'''
        pass
      
    def _update_snake_parts(self):
        '''Update all the parts of the snake.'''
        self.snake_parts.update()
        
    def _update_screen(self):
        '''Update the screen.'''
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)

        # Draw snake parts to the screen.
        for snake_part in self.snake_parts.sprites():
            snake_part.draw_part()

        # Draw foods to the screen.
        self.food.draw_food()

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sg = SnakeGame()
    sg.run_game()
```

---

**food.py**

```
import pygame
from random import randint

class Food:
    '''A class to manage the foods.'''

    def __init__(self, sg):
        '''Initialize the food rect, food color, and other assets.'''
        self.screen = sg.screen
        self.settings = sg.settings
        self.color = self.settings.food_color
        
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.food_width,
                        self.settings.food_height)

        # Initialize the food at a random position.
        self.spawn_food()
    
    def spawn_food(self):
        '''Position the food at a random position.'''
        self.rect.x = randint(0, self.settings.screen_width) 
        self.rect.y = randint(0, self.settings.screen_height) 

    def draw_food(self):
        '''Draw the food to the screen.'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

---

**snake.py**

```
import pygame
import sys

from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class Snake(Sprite):
    '''A class to manage the snake.'''

    def __init__(self, sg):
        '''Initialize the snake's location, size, etc.'''
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = sg.screen
        self.settings = sg.settings
        self.color = self.settings.snake_color
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        
        # Create the snake's rect object and position it.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0, self.settings.snake_width,
                            self.settings.snake_height)
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center

        # Get the precise coordinates of the snake.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        # Set movement flags.
        self.m_right = False
        self.m_left = False
        self.m_up = False
        self.m_down = False

    def update(self):
        '''Update the position of the snake.'''
        if self.m_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:                    
            self.x += self.settings.snake_speed
        if self.m_left and self.rect.left > self.screen_rect.left:
            self.x -= self.settings.snake_speed
        if self.m_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.y += self.settings.snake_speed
        if self.m_up and self.rect.top > self.screen_rect.top:
            self.y -= self.settings.snake_speed

        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y
        
    def draw_part(self):
        '''Draw the snake to the screen.'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

---

**settings.py**

```
class Settings:
    '''Class for game settings.'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialize the game settings.'''

        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (119, 181, 254)  # Blue color

        # Snake settings
        self.snake_width = 20
        self.snake_height = 20
        self.snake_color = (255, 255, 0)  # Yellow color
        self.snake_speed = 1

        # Food settings
        self.food_width = 10
        self.food_height = 10
        self.food_color = (139, 69, 19)  # Brown color
```

I have tried the below pseudo-code to fix this problem:

```
if food_coordinate_x == snake_coordinate_x:
    do something which fixes this issue (I have no idea how to fix this)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general approach is to just draw positions for the food until you are satisfied:

```
food_coordinate_x = sample_new_food()
while food_coordinate_x == snake_coordinate_x:
    food_coordinate_x = sample_new_food()
```

In your specific case this could look something like this:

```
def spawn_food(self, blocked_positions):
    """
    blocked_positions: list of (x, y) pairs of blocked positions on the grid
                       ie the snake body
    """
    
    while True:
        self.rect.x = randint(0, self.settings.screen_width)
        self.rect.y = randint(0, self.settings.screen_height)

        valid = True
        for xb, yb in blocked_positions:
            if xb == self.rect.x and yb == self.rect.y:
                valid = False
                break

        if valid:
            break
```

Another possibility is to just sample from the empty space.
This depends of course on your implementation, but I guess at some point you have a grid for your world, and some part of this world is occupied by the snake.

```py
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
world = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=int)
snake = np.array([[5, 5],  # x and y positions of the cells occupied by the snake
                  [5, 6],  # ordered from head to tail
                  [5, 7],
                  [4, 7],
                  [4, 8],
                  [4, 9],
                  [5, 9],
                  [6, 9],
                  [7, 9]])

world[snake[:, 0], snake[:, 1]] = 1
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

empty_space = np.array(np.nonzero(world == 0)).T

# Sample new food coordinate from the empty space
food_coordinate = empty_space[np.random.randint(low=0, high=len(empty_space)), :]
```

Such a procedure can easily be extended to more obstacles like existing food to further shrink the empty space for sampling. And in the end game when the snake makes up almost the entire screen, in this approach you do not need to sample for a long time, but still just once.

Comment: I should have mentioned that my Python knowledge isn't advanced enough to grasp concepts like arrays and librarias like numpy. Is there any easier way of fixing this problem? By using randint library, for example.

Comment: I made an edit to show you an example for the `spawn_food` method

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now.